# joomla privileges: can't grant allow to add contacts

Tags: joomla, permissions

Operating CiviCRM 4.5.6 on current Joomla  3.5.1.

I have set up three groups which should have different access levels to view, edit and add contacts.
Have configured them to be in group special as suggested elsewhere and allowed them access to Access Administration Interface in global permissions.

When I try to add allow to the add contacts group this automatically resets to "Not Allowed" after I press save..

It went OK with the other privileges but not with add contacts.

Dumbfounded.
Can somebody help?
P.S. where are these privileges stored in Joomla anyway?
Checked all the tables and found nothing which represented the privileges in any way..

Comment: Update to the latest Joomla version, which is now 3.6.4. There were problems with the ACL settings for CiviCrm in earlier versions that are solved in the latetst versions of Joomla.

Comment: @PaulKleingeld This should be an answer IMO!

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest Joomla version, which is now 3.7.4. There were problems with the ACL settings for CiviCrm in earlier versions that are solved in the latetst versions of Joomla.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused what exactly you're trying to do "add contacts" (as in 'create a new contact') or "add contacts to group".